# jQuery not working inside the wordpress's footer.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have to include these code inside the footer.php file of wordpress but it is not working ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#vpb_captcha_code_102').blur(function(){
       var value= jQuery('#vpb_captcha_code_102').val();
      alert(value);
  });
</script>
```

Whereas if i try to run this same code from console it works, please let me know what should i do.

Comment: Try wrapping the whole thing in a [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) block.

Comment: thanks man its working @naththedeveloper

Comment: Or if the element is dynamically appended, use a delegated event handler

Answer (score 0):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is `"ready."` jQuery detects this state of readiness for you.

Please make changes in code as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#vpb_captcha_code_102').blur(function(){
       var value= jQuery('#vpb_captcha_code_102').val();
      alert(value);
  });
});
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: why we use jQuery ,instead of $

Comment: see this article you will get to understand https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/cms/6-things-to-consider-when-using-jquery-with-wordpress.html

Comment: if you want to use `$` instead of `jQuery` then you can use as `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` as a first line of script.